# How to open new tab not in group chrome tab?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Hello I am facing some weird issue and not sure how to fix it, looks like chrome made some update and open new tab in group is there option to change something in my javascript to open new tab in chrome tab not in group tab.

```
<a href="http://google.com" class="button-1" onclick="open_win()">Button</a>
<script type="text/javascript">
            
                        function open_win() {
                
                window.open("http://bing.com")
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function openWindow(url, title) {
    var myWindow = window.open(url, title, "height=640,width=960,toolbar=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,location=no,status=no");
}
```

**reference:**
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp